# Is there any method to manage overcrowding modifiers in a single object?

Tags: modifiers

I am applying laplacian deform with lots of hooks on a single object, it is nice to have a folder to organize them. But seems like blender is not prividing such feature. Is there any work around?

Comment: It's one of the design limitations of the modifier stack in Blender. I've never used it but you might want to explore modifier panel overhaul addons like the [Modifier List add-on](https://github.com/Symstract/modifier_list)

Answer (score 1):

Using Geometry nodes seems like a perfect solution for this. You can organise nodes nicely with frames and labels as well as create groups. You can make it very visual and intuitive and you have the whole node editor dedicated for them. I don't think any add-on will beat this in the properties editor in terms of possibilities for organising stuff. Hook modifier functionality should be easy to replicate.

Comment: Could you please provide more information, for example where should I start with, what geometry node should I use?

Comment: It's hard to advice without knowing full context of your workflow. You could ask a new question specifically about using Geometry Nodes for your specific situation and provide more details and all the context about your goals and what you need. There are some really advanced Geometry Nodes experts here on BSE providing amazing answers about using them. There might be some amount of learning involved, but this is a very useful tool in general and it's worth learning anyway.